# Importing Android Project into Eclipse ADT seems to be leaving a necessary folder

Tags: android, eclipse, import, unity-game-engine

**Background:**
I have created several games using Unity3D and have decided to try and release them; I am hoping to add advertisements to the projects but have been struggling in using >1 plugin. I have found threads leading me to believe the issue is to do with how Android Activities work and that multiple plugins are preventing each other from declaring themselves Activities. In an attempt to understand this I have been exporting Unity3D projects with single plugins into Eclipse to try and see the Java code they use to create their Activity.

**The Problem:**
I have made a project in Unity that is nothing but the Google Play Services plugin and buttons to activate it.

If I compile this to .apk format and install it on my devices it works fine and logs into Google play services without problem.

However if I export it to Eclipse and run it the "Sign In" button I've created does nothing.

**More info:**
I noticed that when creating the "Google Android Project" export from Unity3D it creates four folders: one for my GUI code and three for the plugin. Eclipse ADT though will only import three of these.

The fourth folder is called "MainLibProj" and contains an executable .jar called "play-games-plugin-support" and a properties file; so I thought perhaps Eclipse was overlooking a file necessary for the plugin to run.

I have repeated the import multiple times with new workspaces, cleaned and re-built etc. and tried to move the files across manually.

There are no errors or console warnings given in Eclipse.

When I right click on the Projects main package within the package explorer in Eclipse and check its properties there is a red cross with "MainLibProj" next to it, but clicking the add button opens an empty window.

What tells Eclipse what it should and should not import?
Am I right in thinking this is the issue or is the MainLibProj folder irrelevant to Eclipse?

P.S this is my first Stack post so sorry if this is inadequate.